# Meteor only inserting an ID and no other data after removing insecure package

Tags: meteor

After removing the insecure package when I try to do an insert it just creates a new record with only and _id

on the server I have allowed the inserting on the Customers.collection

```
Customers.allow({
    insert: function(userID) {
        console.log(userID === userID);
        return userID === userID;
    }
});
```

on the client I am calling insert and passing it the userID and the form data

```
Template.tabs.events({
'submit form#customer' : function (event) {

    console.log(event.type + event.currentTarget);

    if (event.type === 'click' || event.type === 'submit') {

        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var state = $("#state").val();
        var zip = $("#zip").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var fax = $("#fax").val();

        doc = {user_id: this.userID, name: name, address: address, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, phone: phone, fax: fax}

        if(Customers.insert(this.userID, doc)) {
            console.log("Inserted");
            $("#name").val(null);
            $("#address").val(null);
            $("#city").val(null);
            $("#state").val(null);
            $("#zip").val(null);
            $("#phone").val(null);
            $("#fax").val(null);
        }
    }
}
});
```

I have also tried to wrap the insert in a meteor method and do a method call from the client instead with the same result.

here is the method and the call from the client

```
Meteor.methods({
    newCustomer: function (userID, record) {
        Customers.insert(userID, record);
                    console.log("Inserted");
    }
});
```

and on the client instead of the insert statement im doing as follows.

```
Meteor.call("newCustomer", this.userID, doc);
```

I have not been able to make out any other solutions from the meteor docs on trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks to be this line:

```
if(Customers.insert(this.userID, doc)) {
```

Your document inserted should be something like this, the document being inserted is the argument

```
if(Customers.insert(doc)) {
```

And your allow function needs to check the actual document:

```
Customers.allow({
    insert: function(userID,doc) {
        return userID === doc.user_id;
    }
});
```

Also change your document owner, `this.userId` is meant to be used in publish on the server or a `Meteor.methods`. To get the user Id of a logged in user elsewhere use `Meteor.userId`

```
doc = {user_id: Meteor.userId(), name: name, address: address, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, phone: phone, fax: fax}
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the code I listed in the question but in my code its the same both are doc. I just dbl checked and it still not the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer hope it helps!

Comment: So the problem changed now I just keep getting a "insert failed: Access denied"